# Keep output of apply as a dict in pandas categorical DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, categorical-data

Let's start with a simple `pandas.DataFrame`. (I am on pandas 0.24.2 but I have been able to reproduce my problem on version 1.0.1  too)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 4, 4]})    
print(df)
>>>    a  b
    0  1  2
    1  2  4
    2  3  4
```

I want to know what are the different values in each column of my dataframe and how many occurences there are, each column represented in a nice dictionary. (I know that converting to dictionaries this way may not be the best practice, but I'll need it for my illustration)

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())
>>> a    {3: 1, 2: 1, 1: 1}
    b          {4: 2, 2: 1}
dtype: object
```

So far so good right ? What happens if my dataframe is of a different type, let's say categories ? I would expect the same results, right ?

Absolutely not:

```
df = df.astype('category') # Let's keep the same values, but now as type categorical
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())
>>>      a    b
     1  1.0  NaN
     2  1.0  1.0
     3  1.0  NaN
     4  NaN  2.0
```

It is really weird that I get at first a `pd.Series`, and then a `pd.DataFrame`.
Any idea on why this behavior exists, and more importantly how to prevent that from happening ?

EDIT: this seems to work as long as one column of the original dataframe is a categorical one.
so having `df['a'] = df['a'].astype('category']` yields the same results as my second example

EDIT 2: as per @jon-clements comment, I tried with different arguments for `result_type`, to no avail

Comment: Note that your initial starting `df` is invalid... think you meant `"b": [2, 4, 4]` there...

Comment: My bad, corrected !

Comment: You say you want to save your data as JSON. Why not just use `pandas.DataFrame.to_json`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, my example is a bit far fetched, will remove it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I found the idea for a quick fix right after finishing to type my question: just convert to "object" every column in the dataframe before doing my counts

```py
df = df.astype('object') # the df is originally categorical here
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())
```

Returns the expected results.

I will keep my question open in case someone finds a less hacky answer, and of course can explain as to why this behavior !

Comment: I don't have time to check right now... but I suspect it's something to do with how the result of the `apply` is intepreted... eg: for categories it can default to expanding... For instance, if you do what you had originally, you can do: `df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict(), result_type='expand')` to get the same behaviour as with categories... but that's just a rather weird way of writing: `df.apply(pd.value_counts)`...

Comment: Right, this is a weird way of writing it, this may be why no one encountered that behavior previously. using `df.apply(pd.value_counts)` returns the same weird DataFrame containing NaNs both for categorical and non-categorical dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens. But a way around this is just to do a list comprehension:

```
df = df.astype('category')
pd.Series({c:df[c].value_counts().to_dict() for c in df.columns})
```

Output:

```
a    {3: 1, 2: 1, 1: 1}
b          {4: 2, 2: 1}
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: dict(zip(x.index.get_level_values(1), x)))
```

Outputs (irrelevant whether it's `category` or not):

```py
a    {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
b          {4: 2, 2: 1}
dtype: object
```